# Possible to bitmask more values than an int can hold?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, enums

I have 36 Bool flags that are related to one another.  Is there any way to enum this, or is an array / something else my only option?

At first I tried to use a bitmask enum for this, but I realized that these are overflowing the Enum size and giving me bad results.

I do not need to combine these like an options mask (they are independent of one another), just group.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question, then the following might work:

```
enum flags
{
  .. 36 appropriatly named entries
};

long long int myFlags = 0LL;

int getFlag( enum flags whichFlag )
{
    return( (myFlags&(1<<whichFlag)? 1:0 );
}

void setFlag( enum flags whichFlag )
{
    myFlags |= (1<<whichFlag);
}
```

Comment: This won't work on architectures where `int` is not at least 36-bit (like x86). In fact, it invokes undefined behavior, because 36 is larger than the max allowed shift for 32-bit ints.

Comment: I tried this and it appears to be working fine - all had to do is cast the one first like 1ULL<<whichFlag. Also as recommended in other posts i made the backing ivar a uint64_t

Answer (score 0):

In C, an enum is basically nothing else than just an int; as such, enums are limited to the maximum size of an integer.
If you want to have an arbitrary number of flags, you could use a bitfield:

```
struct flags {
    unsigned f0 :1;
    unsigned f1 :1;
    unsigned f2 :1;
    unsigned f3 :1;
    unsigned f4 :1;
    unsigned f5 :1;
    unsigned f6 :1;
    unsigned f7 :1;


    ...

    unsigned f35 :1;
};

struct flags f;

f.f33 = 1;
f.f14 = 0;
```